# How to get the largest city of country using only the country code in PHP?

Tags: php, city

i want to input the country code like "fr" and get the largest city "paris" , and if possible also the continent, in PHP !

Comment: you want code for this? We're not here to do your job for you. Write your own code. You need pointers to an API that can do such geo-type queries? We're not a search engine.

Comment: The [geoip extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) might help you, or look into the Google maps APIs...

Comment: U need to specify the data source IMHO

Comment: I love to see such questions. Even more when those are answered. Nice.

Comment: @Miguelo : i didn't try anything, i'm working around Carbon https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon !

Comment: then first try something and comeback when you run into problems

Comment: @Marc : i'm not asking you to do my job, i'm looking for an API , Library or some open source database that i can use!

Comment: @One Trick : thank you , the extension is helpful !

Comment: @EvilThinker: Asking others for off-site resources like libraries, APIs or databases is off-topic. But thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend to your needs, I already added the city you asked for:

```
$largest = [
    'fr' => 'paris',
];

$code = 'fr';

echo $largest[$code];
```

You can further improve this by wrapping it into a class supporting [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/ArrayAccess) giving a default value in case it does not exist.

Comment: Epic fail... m8 what is the reason for this :D

Comment: thanks but what i'm looking for exactly is a database with largest cities !

Comment: @EvilThinker: And you weren't able to google for those? Poor boy, try harder I'd say. Why don't you just take http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_cities_and_second_largest_cities_by_country ?

Comment: @hakre because it's working trust me , but i got a solution i will post it !

Comment: i needed to the get the largest city of a particular country to use in a timezone identifier in Carbon library , but i got a pretty useful function print_r(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, $country_code));